# CUDA __host__ __device__ variables

Tags: c++, cuda, gpgpu, nvcc

In CUDA function type qualifiers `__device__` and `__host__` can be used together in which case the function is compiled for both the host and the device. This allows to eliminate copy-paste. However, there is no such thing as `__host__ __device__` variable. I'm looking for an elegant way to do something like this:

```
__host__ __device__ const double common = 1.0;

__host__ __device__ void foo() {
    ... access common
}

__host__ __device__ void bar() {
    ... access common
}
```

I found out that the following code complies and runs without errors.
(all results were obtained on Ubuntu 14.04 with CUDA 7.5 and gcc 4.8.4 as a host compiler)

```
#include <iostream>

__device__ const double off = 1.0;

__host__ __device__ double sum(int a, int b) {
    return a + b + off;
}

int main() {
    double res = sum(1, 2);
    std::cout << res << std::endl;
    cudaDeviceReset();
    return 0;
}

$ nvcc main.cu -o main && ./main
4
```

In fact, `nvcc --cuda main.cu` translates cu-file into this:

```
...
static const double off = (1.0);
# 5 "main.cu"
double sum(int a, int b) {
# 6 "main.cu"
return (a + b) + off;
# 7 "main.cu"
}
# 9 "main.cu"
int main() {
# 10 "main.cu"
double res = sum(1, 2);
# 11 "main.cu"
(((std::cout << res)) << (std::endl));
# 12 "main.cu"
cudaDeviceReset();
# 13 "main.cu"
return 0;
# 14 "main.cu"
}
...
```

But, no surprise, if the variable `off` is declared without `const` qualifier (`__device__ double off = 1.0`) I get the following output:

```
$ nvcc main.cu -o main && ./main
main.cu(7): warning: a __device__ variable "off" cannot be directly read in a host function

3
```

So, returning back to the original question, can I rely on this behavior with global `__device__ const` variable? If not, what are the other options?

**UPD** By the way, the above behavior doesn't reproduce on Windows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For ordinary floating point or integral types it should be sufficient simply to mark the variable as `const` at global scope:

```
const double common = 1.0;
```

It should then be usable in any subsequent function, whether host, `__host__`, `__device__`, or `__global__`.

This is supported in the documentation [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#const-variables), subject to various restrictions:

> Let 'V' denote a namespace scope variable or a class static member variable that has **const** qualified type and does not have execution space annotations (e.g., `__device__`, `__constant__`, `__shared__`). V is considered to be a host code variable.
>
> The value of V may be directly used in device code, if
>   V has been initialized with a constant expression before the point of use, and
>   it has one of the following types:
>
> - builtin floating point type except when the Microsoft compiler is used as the host compiler,
> - builtin integral type.
>
> Device source code cannot contain a reference to V or take the address of V.

In other cases, some possible options are:

1. Use a compiler macro defined constant:

   ```
   #define COMMON 1.0
   ```
2. Use templating, if the range of choices on the variable is discrete and limited.
3. For other options/cases, it may be necessary to manage explicit host and device copies of the variable, e.g. using `__constant__` memory on the device, and a corresponding copy on the host.  Host and device paths within the `__host__` `__device__` function that accesses the variable could then differentiate behavior based on a nvcc compiler macro  (e.g. `#ifdef __CUDA_ARCH__ ...`